# Controls Project: Help needed finding 3rd order system

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, pid-control

I'm in need of help finding a third-order or higher system in which I can derive a transfer function. We have a class project in which we need to find a real-life example of the system that equates to a 3rd order system or higher.

The problem that I have is that I do not know what a third-order system looks like in real life. I can find a lot of examples of 2nd order systems (acceleration, velocity, and displacement). But no 3rd order! Help!

**Project guidelines:**

**Step 1:** Find a system of interest to you, discuss why this system is of specific interest to you and why this is a good topic for the class project;

**Step 2:** Model the system in three forms: differential equations, transfer function, and state-space representation. Note if the system is nonlinear, please linearize it first;

**Step 3:** Find and plot system output under step input and another input of your choice. Discuss the physical implications;

**Step 4:** Study the system stability, discuss the physical meaning of instability in your case;

Step 5: Assume a negative unity feedback system,  two possible controllers:

$\ C_1(s)=k_0 $

$\ C_2s= k_p + k_ds+k_i \frac 1s $

• Design the two controllers, so that the system is stable.

• With all your designed control parameter values, what are the feedback system’s output under step input and another input of your choice?

• What are the steady-state errors under the four cases (2 controllers, 2 inputs)?

Comment: Rest assured, when you try wrapping it with sufficiently prompt control, *any* system will go right through 3rd-order and straight to *multiple poles omygodomygod*.  Is this a thought experiment, or are you expected to haul physical objects into class?

Answer (score 2):

The [Temperature Control Lab](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/ArduinoTemperatureControl) is a third order system with heater 1 as the system input (controller output) and temperature 2 as the process variable. There are model development and control development modules in MATLAB and Python.

[image: TCLab]

Model Development

- Simulate Step Response
- Convective Heat Transfer
- Radiative Heat Transfer
- Linearize Energy Balance
- First Order Plus Dead Time (Graphical)
- First Order Plus Dead Time (Regression)
- Impulse Response (Analytic Solution)
- State Space Simulation
- Second Order Response
- **Higher (Third or Fifth) Order Response**

Control Development

- Controller Design
- P-Only Control
- PI Control
- PID Control
- PI Control Tuning
- PID Control Tuning
- PID with Feedforward
- Heater Actuator
- Temperature Sensor
- Block Diagram
- On/Off Control

Here is the [schedule for the course](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/CourseSchedule) I developed with TCLab as the hands-on portion of the class. The topics cover almost all of your required topics.